# Add class on svg path element

Tags: jquery, html, svg

In my project I have an SVG world map with different paths with different id's and one class of `map-path`. For each country click I want to add class on each path. My HTML is like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="">
    <path id="map_1" class="map-path" ......>
    <path id="map_2" class="map-path" ......>
    <path id="map_3" class="map-path" ......>
    <path id="map_4" class="map-path" ......>
    <!-- more <path /> elements... -->
</svg>
```

Comment: _For each country click_ what do you mean by `country`? `path` tag?

Comment: Hi @Zakaria Acharki, I mean each <path> tag..

Answer (score 16):

JQuery function `addClass()` will not work here and can't add a class to an SVG.

Use `.attr()` instead :

```
$('body').on('click','.map-path',function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "map-path newclass");
});
```

You could use pure js solution with `setAttribute()` method :

```
$('body').on('click','.map-path',function(e) {
    e.target.setAttribute("class", "map-path newclass");
});
```

Or use `classList.add()` that works in modern browsers :

```
$('body').on('click','.map-path',function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('newclass');
});
```

Hope this helps.